# NextJs api req.body is object in middleware but becomes string in route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Here's the middleware, where I handle the origin and CORS:

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)

  const origin = requestHeaders.get('origin') ?? ''
  if (!allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Forbidden' }, { status: 403 })
  } else {
    requestHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin)
  }

  if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return NextResponse.json({}, { status: 200, headers: requestHeaders })
  }

  return NextResponse.next({
    headers: requestHeaders,
  })
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/api/:path*',
}
```

If I log `typeof request.body` here, it logs object. Here's the api route:

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<any>
) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).send({ message: 'Only POST requests are allowed' })
  }

  // It logs string for some reason and I need to parse it
  console.log(typeof req.body)
  const { token } = JSON.parse(req.body)

  // some code

  return res.json({
    data: captchaResponse,
  })
}
```

My next.config.js is just a plain module.exports. For other routes, I don't need to parse req.body as it behaves as expected, what might be the reason? I checked the bodyParser and it has the default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Middleware**: Your middleware could mess with the `request.body`. Double-check it isn't changing the `req.body` to a string somewhere.
2. **Headers**: When sending data to your API, set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` from the client-side. This helps Next.js know you're sending JSON data.
3. **Client-Side Check**: Whatever tool or code you're using to send requests, ensure it's always sending data the same way. Sometimes a tiny change can cause things to act up.
4. **Quick Fix**: For now, you can use a simple if-check to parse the body only if it's a string:

```js
let data = typeof req.body === 'string' ? JSON.parse(req.body) : req.body;
const { token } = data;
```

But remember, this is just a patch-up. You'll want to dig in and find out why this is happening to ensure it doesn't cause issues later on!

Comment: Yeah, you're right about second point, I solved it yesterday, anyway your answer is good!